# How to find logs of desktop crash (of wayland?)

Tags: gnome, xorg, crash, wayland

I've got a new Dell XPS13 on which I installed Ubuntu 19.04. I've been using it with Wayland for a week or so. It works smoother than X11, but it also crashes regularly after my laptop has been in sleep and I type in my password again. After typing my password and hitting enter the screen flickers a bit and I get back to the login which you get after booting up. All my opened windows are then gone. I assume the problem is Wayland but I'm not sure.

I would like to get Wayland in a working state, but a display server is way over my head. So maybe I can help the Wayland developers or the developer of the application that caused the Wayland crash by providing my crash logs to them.

How can I find out what crashes my desktop?

If an application caused Wayland to crash, where can I find logs for this? I normally have a dozen programs open so I don't want to go over the logs of all of them. Are there any Wayland logs which logs the problems or the problematic application?